# How to store fuel tablets for travel

Tags: gear

I'm looking into using some fuel tablets for cooking with a stove like [this esbit](http://www.rei.com/product/653343/esbit-pocket-stove) as a backup/emergency stove when rafting.  However I have heard that the fuel can easily foul food, clothing, etc.  What's the recommended way to store and pack the fuel *when rafting* to help prevent package rupture?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I keep mine in a small freezer bag, which I replace each trip. I keep individual tablets in foil so they don't crumble as much. The foil also helps avoid touching them. If you're worried about the freezer bag wearing out you could double it up but I haven't found the need.

Comment: Aso, the container for burning the fuel often gets that hexamine smell, keep it separate from your food.

Answer (score 2):

They can easily foul food and clothing when they come into contact with it - but keep them separate and you should be fine. I tend to wrap up individually in foil, then in a big foil layer to make a "pack" of fuel cells, then wrap them in a bag. Unless you're really bashing your pack about, there shouldn't be any problem with that setup.